# Best approach to serve static content within a regular page

Tags: plugins, customization, pages, design

I am developing a wordpress plugin which is supposed to display static forms to the front end users. These forms will be protected by another plugin managing user logins/registrations on page level.

My content should therefore be managed within a regular wordpress page. My content will then be the only thing displayed in the content section of that page. What is the best design approach for my plugin to insert that content?

Shortcodes would be an option, but I think they are not meant to be used for this as my content should not be inbetween other content but standalone.

Comment: Suggestion: Adding a template to the list of selectable ones on the page editing page. But I think that won't work with custom themes as my content should be displayed within the content area of the original template of the custom theme and not serve as replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`the_content` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) to override page content and output whatever you want. [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) can help restrict your filter to running on specific pages.

Comment: Looks good, but doesn't seem to allow any filter criteria that does not have some other use already

Comment: I would just store page IDs in an option and check those when deciding when to apply the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode) to generate your form in the content area. Just don't put any other content in that area. That's the only way to keep the template and only replace the content section with your form.